Running power 150’ to Workshop
I’m coming off my main panel to my shop 150’ away into a sub-panel. What’s the minimum Direct Bury Aluminum Line I can use?
I already have a 200amp panel. Can that be used or should I get a smaller sub-panel?

You want to do a load calculation on your main panel first.
This will show how big of a feed breaker you can use for the workshop panel.
All panels are rated for up to maximum amps, not minimum.
Once you have the load calculation and the size of the breaker to feed the sub panel, you can decide on the the wire size.
Wire size is based on the minimum gauge allowed for the size of the breaker.  Can use larger gauges than what is the minimum allowed on the breaker.  For 150 feet, bumping the wire gauge up one size might be nice.  There are tables online to figure out the wire gauge for the breaker size and length of run.

A subpanel with a 200A rating is perfectly fine for all feeders from 15 amps to 200 amps.
People get voltage drop wrong a lot. Mistake #1 is treating 3% like it's set in stone.  No, it's only wire salesman propaganda, except in Canada.  Mistake #2 is calculating it based on feeder breaker trip - no, it should be calculated on actual load.  Note that you're only allowed to "plan to use" 80% of feeder capacity, so if you have a 125A breaker with 120A feeder, that's 96A - compute on that at most, not 125A.
150' is barely on the cusp of even bothering to think about voltage drop.  It may be a moot point anyway.....
... since conventional wisdom is that 2 AWG aluminum is at a "sweet spot" of price, performance and availability, giving 90 amps for a little over a buck a foot.  You probably don't need 90 amps in a shop, so there's your "wire size enlargement" right there - mission accomplished, final answer, that was easy!
However if you want honest 100A feeder, use 1 AWG aluminum.  If you want 120A feeder, use 1/0 AWG aluminum. Any larger than that is fairly pointless since breakers over 125A are costly. (you use a 125A breaker on 120A feeder due to the Round Up Rule.)
However, if you really, really want to bring a full 200A over to the workshop, using a subfeed lug in the main panel... that's possible. Normally this would take 250 kcmil wire. But since the 200A service constitutes the entire service to a dwelling, rule 310.12 comes into play, allowing 4/0 AWG aluminum.  It sensibly says no feeder needs to be larger than the service wires need to be.  So 4/0 AWG will do it.

And conveniently this is why 2/2/4/6, 2/2/2/4, and 4/0 / 4/0 / 2/0 / 4 MHF or Mobile Home Feeder cable is readily available.

not sure why there's 2 other answers here that does not directly answer your question... yes you size the wire based on the breaker not the rated amps of the panel, and here is that information.
https://paigeconnected.com/calculators/wiresize-calculator
or
https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop
this is for either 150' or 200' distance, and 5% specified as allowable voltage drop

breaker          minimum           minimum
  amp          Copper AWG         Alum AWG
   60              4                 3
  100              1               2/0
  125            2/0               2/0
  150            2/0               4/0
  200            4/0               250-mcm

and to answer your question interpreted literally as you typed it, the minimum direct bury Al wire you can use is 8awg... with a 15 amp breaker.

That table looks very wrong.  Feeders use the 75C column in 310.16.  If it provides all the loads of a dwelling, it uses the more favorable 310.12.  Note the Round Up Rule 240.4(B) also enters the picture on a feeder, placing a "125A breaker" at #2 Cu (115A actual) or #1/0 AL (120A actual). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp4SyoB5D5s

You can put a 200 amp sub panel on any circuit size up to 200 amps. The breaker that feeds it from the main panel will be appropriately sized to protect the wire.
Since you haven't described how many amps you want to put on the sub panel, I can't really tell you wire sizing. What I will suggest is taking a long look at using Mobile Home Feeder cable. It's rated for outdoor use, relatively inexpensive per foot, and comes in pretty useful sizes.
